# RESTful expand by default

Tags: yii, yii2

How can I return model relations without adding expand parameter in url? I tried add some code in model

```
public function fields()
{
    $fields = parent::fields();

    $fields['profile'] = $this->profile;

    return $fields;
}
```

But i am getting the error:

```
call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, no array or string given
```

This method works:

```
$_GET['expand'] = 'profile';
```

but it's bad solution.

Comment: You probably know this already, but what does $this->profile give you? It needs to be either a string or an array.

Comment: @JoeMiller relation value is null, I don't understand what should i put there

Comment: I don't think you can do this automatically, you have to use the 'expand' parameter in the url to get the profile, you can't include it automatically, as far as I can work out.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
public function fields()
{
    $fields = parent::fields();
    $fields[] = 'profile';
    return $fields;
}
```

Make sure you have set the relation. Worked for me

Comment: Seems I have the same problem. The relational data returns null. The same method is used for other relationships and then it just works.

Comment: Old post but does anyone know if you can unset fields from the related model side? I have pk in my tables 'cidref' and when I use:

`  unset($fields['cidref']);` 

it  is removed from the initial model not the related one